# Is there a way to create a calendar view as such?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have been trying to bend my mind around this in SPD 2010 and I can't seem to figure it out.
Is this possible to make a calendar view as such?

[image]

Comment: looks a lot like the group work list functionality

Comment: Eric I didn't know that existed! Almost there. Would you know how I can place the names to the left in alphabetical order and also by a group? The view setting have some options missing like sort by.
Are those templates completely customizable?

Comment: OK I have tried this and it seems like it is missing a very important feature. It doesn't recall the entries and doesn't keep multiple items as well. After page is refreshed all you is yours. I have seen and tried a workaround but all it seems to do is add the names but I can't add correlating entries/events for each name like above.